# How to classify principal bundles over a 2 dimensional surface?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

I just want to how much people know about this at the moment? I thought this is elementary and may be of execrise level, but a quick google search showed serious papers written on this subject (like [this](https://dspace.ist.utl.pt/bitstream/2295/1258535/1/dissertacao5.pdf)). Maybe I asked this prematurely and more research on my side is needed.

If some expert at here knows the answer already, please provide a hint instead of a straightforward answer. This way I can probably learn something myself.

Comment: What other dimension can a surface be?

Comment: To be specific so not to be confused with an algebraic surface.

Comment: I think what is much better understood is the case of a surface bundle over some other space, and this is related to representations into the mapping class group.

Comment: It't not exactly what you looking for, but a text I recently found very useful that seems related, is http://www.math.columbia.edu/~scautis/math428/notes-bundles.pdf. 
Considering the amount of work needed there, I don't expect your question to be elementary, nor of exercise level.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_bundle#Classification_of_principal_bundles

Comment: @SteveD: Thank you! I thought this primarily in terms of how $G$ may define a covariant derivative on $M$, and if the connection is flat whether I can conclude certain things. But I never thought this way about it.

Comment: @user17786: The classification of principal bundles over the sphere is done via the classifying space, see for example Streerod. I just do not know how it works in the case of the surface.

Comment: At the level of generality at which you posed your question there is little more to be said apart from recalling the fact that $G$-principal bundles over a (paracompact!) space $X$ are classified by homotopy classes of maps $X\to BG$. If you have a specific group in mind, one might be able to do better.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: So if I limit my groups to be classicial Lie groups. Then I might hope for a deeper classification theorem?

Comment: Let me think about this for a while.

Comment: No, he answer would be pretty much the same. If you want something explicit, pick *a* group :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I see. Let me pick $SU(3)$ (my favoriate Lie group) and see how it goes...

Comment: Well, now find a description of $BSU(3)$ good enough to compute the set of homotopy classes $[X,BSU(3)]$.

Comment: @user32240: $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ is simply connected, and hence $B\mathrm{SU}(3)$ is $2$-connected. Since a surface is $2$-dimensional, it follows that $[\Sigma, B\mathrm{SU}(3)] = 0$ for any surface $\Sigma$, _i.e._ up to isomorphism the only $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ bundle over a surface $\Sigma$ is the trivial bundle.

Comment: @HenryT.Horton - If $M$ is 2-dimensional and $N$ is 2-connected, why is $[M,N]=0$? (I'm new to homotopy theory.)

Comment: @DaanMichiels: The surface can be think as a 2-dimensional CW-complex, you extend the map over each skeleton and since $BSU(3)$ is 2-connected any such extension would be homotopically equivalent. This means ther eis only one bundle (the trivial one) up to homotopy.